# Everything is normal on local GAE server but ClassNotFound in production

Tags: java, google-app-engine, classnotfoundexception

My application is perfectly working when running locally but crashes with ClassNotFoundException every time. I read that this might occur when you forgot to include some dependencies to WEB-INF/libs, but class in question is my own and doesn't use any dependencies. I looked into builded application folder and .class file for this class is there. What could be wrong?

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run ERROR: could not find handlers.user.battle.BattleVerifyHandler got a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: battle/Utilities/UnitTypeHelperBase
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: battle/Utilities/UnitTypeHelperBase
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-3aeeaae5c6df581c(Request.java)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:111)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run.prepareRunObject(Run.java:252)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run.initialise(Run.java:188)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Run.initialise(Run.java:133)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase.initialise(RuleBase.java:284)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRule.initialise(NormalRule.java:118)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf.initialise(Conf.java:440)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf.<init>(Conf.java:132)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.loadUrlRewriterLocal(UrlRewriteFilter.java:294)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.loadUrlRewriter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:262)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.init(UrlRewriteFilter.java:253)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doStart(FilterHolder.java:97)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:662)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: battle.Utilities.UnitTypeHelperBase
    at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-3aeeaae5c6df581c(Request.java)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: Always post the actual exception.

Comment: Help readers by including the actual class name.  Is it "handlers.user.battle.BattleVerifyHandler" ?  Including a copy of your web.xml might also help.  An error in the project settings might also cause the problem, so try creating a new project and pasting your source code into that.